# Property Definition in h.file

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS: must every iVar really be property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031230/ios-must-every-ivar-really-be-property)

I really would appreciate if somebody could explain to me why some properties are defined in the interface statement and some as @property ones.

```
@interface PlacesParser : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *arrPlaces;   

    TBXML *tbxml;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *arrPlaces;

-(void)loadRecords:(NSString *)records;
-(void)traverseElement:(TBXMLElement *)element;

@end
```

In my example we got "arrPlaces" as @property

and "arrPlaces" within the interface.

Answer (score 3):

The thing in the interface is not actually a property, it is just a plain old instance variable. The `@property` statement is what makes it a property (giving you the setters and getters). You used to need both, but you don't anymore. If you want your field to be a property with those generated methods, you can leave out the initial field declaration.

Comment: Thanks Dima ... So why and when would I then define properties within the @interface {...}?

Comment: @mogio: You can't define properties in the `@interface {}` block. Only instance variables. Properties go after the braces and do not actually define storage.

Comment: again, those are NOT properties, they are just ivars. You would declare an ivar without making it a property if you don't want generated accessors/mutators (for example if perhaps it's only getting set/used once so you don't want the overhead). You will probably just want to make most things properties. [More info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719788/property-vs-instance-variable).

Comment: ok got it. Everything within the interface are just variables that exist for the life time of the object. And references that are declared with @property are actual property methods (Setter/Getter). Public values that can be changes or read by external objects.

Answer (score 0):

[What is the difference between ivars and properties in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172810/what-is-the-difference-between-ivars-and-properties-in-objective-c)

This thread really opened my eyes. Great explonation to my question.