# what is the difference between '.' and '->' iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, syntax, member-access

Ok, I am confused!
I used to use -> whenever I accessed my instance objects, but now I see that after I set them in my application:didFinishLaunching like this:

```
self->counter = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
```

Down the road I got thrown out with an Exception, checked my debugger and saw that counter was pointing to a `<non objective c object>`

I changed the line to :

```
self.counter = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
```

And now I see in the debugger that I have yes another variable.

So, what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self->counter = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];` uses direct access to an ivar. With `self`, it is equal to `counter = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];` where `counter` is an ivar. That is to say `self->` is a redundant scope qualification within an instance method.

`self.counter = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];` is syntactic sugar for `[self setCounter:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];`. Specifically, the declaration dynamically messages the object's setter for counter. [Although there are exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086736/why-would-you-use-an-ivar/9086811#9086811), you should favor using the accessor when not in a partially constructed/destructed state.

Comment: To add to this correct answer, the form `self->counter` is not only redundant in an instance method scope, it throws a warning (or error) outside that scope, unless the ivar is marked (bizarrely...) `@public`

Comment: @NSBum Right +1, although access is inconsistent and complex in ObjC. If you are writing for newer ABIs, then access is checked correctly. Older ABIs or compilers, then may instead emit a warning. It's `@protected` by default if declared in an `@interface` and `@private` by default when declared in an `@implementation` block. clang also permits access to privates in an `@implementation` body (e.g. if using a static function) -- as expected, it is an error outside the `@implementation` body  O_O

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about the difference between iVars and properties. There's already a great answer on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172810/what-is-the-difference-between-ivars-and-properties-in-objective-c).