# Difference between @property and variable within interface declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

What's the difference between putting a variable inside of the `@interface{}` declaration in a header file, and putting in a `@property` after that declaration?

E.g.,

```
@interface GameCenterManager : NSObject
{
GKInvite* pendingInvite;
}
@end
```

as opposed to

```
@interface GameCenterManager : NSObject
@property (weak, nonatomic) GKInvite* pendingInvite
@end
```

Comment: Similar to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172810/what-is-the-difference-between-ivars-and-properties-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Declaring  a property generates getters and setters for the instance variable, according to the criteria within the parenthesis.**
>
> **Defining the variables in the brackets simply declares them instance variables.**

Following are some links that provides more info on these.

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/dynamic-ivars-solving-fragile-base.html

[Is there a difference between an "instance variable" and a "property" in Objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843632/is-there-a-difference-between-an-instance-variable-and-a-property-in-objecti)

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2008/12/outlets-property-vs-instance-variable.html

Comment: Not sure, but to generate the getter and setter you must synthesize no?

Comment: @PatricioIgnacioFariaValdivi Not anymore. Just `@property` is enough, it'll create an iVar automatically with a underscore prefix. You can test this with `@property (nonatomic) NSString *foo` in interface, without synthesize you can get _foo in you implementation.

Comment: @PatricioIgnacioFariaValdivi You need not synthesize from ios6 as it is synthesized automatically by the system.  where as previous versions need you to synthesize manually,

Comment: Awesome, good to know, thanks. But well, if he is using and iOS < 6 he must synthesize :)

Comment: @PatricioIgnacioFariaValdivi yes exactly! :)

Comment: It's not the operating system that matters, it's the compiler, @VinayakKini.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes it should be compiler. Thanks for helping me to rectify my answer :)