# Assign multiple variables to a class instance

Tags: objective-c, variables

i have defined a new class called **StockHolding** that has all the methods and instance variables of the class **NSObject**. And added 3 instance variables:

```
@interface StockHolding : NSObject
{
    float purchaseSharePrice;
    float currentSharePrice;
    int numberOfShares;
}
```

Also, i've added instance methods

```
- (void)setPurchaseSharePrice:(float)p;
- (void)setCurrentSharePrice:(float)c;
- (void)setNumberOfShares:(int)n;
```

At **main.m** file i created an instance of class

```
StockHolding *stock = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
```

and want to create and object with variables

```
StockHolding *a = [stock setPurchaseSharePrice:2.30 setCurrentSharePrice:4.50 setNumberOfShares:40];
```

but receiving error

> No visible @interface for 'StockHolding' declares the selector 'setPurchaseSharePrice:setCurrentSharePrice:setNumberOfShares:'

What i'm doing wrong? Or its just not proper use of inherited instance.

I saw example:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger day = [cal ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit
                               forDate:now];
```

or this won't work?

Comment: maybe you want to use KVO or something similar?

Comment: @loldop maybe you're going a little too fast for somebody who clearly is new to objective-C and probably to OOP in general ;)

Comment: @Cyrille sorry, if I too fast, but I didn't see, that you are new to OOP and obj-c:) ok, so, look at this, maybe it can help you ;) [charm about objective-c object handling](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html)

Comment: Maybe KVO is something too advanced for somebody who hasn't fully grasped the basic concepts of message sending in obj-C, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In StockHolding.h

```
@interface StockHolding : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) float purchaseSharePrice;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float currentSharePrice;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int numberOfShares;

@end
```

In StockHolding.m

```
#import "StockHolding.h"

@implementation StockHolding ()

@synthesize purchaseSharePrice;
@synthesize currentSharePrice;
@synthesize numberOfShares;

@end
```

Now, every other class where you want to set the values of StockHolding,

1. Import StockHolding `#import "StockHolding.h"`
2. create an object `StockHolding *aStockHolding = [[StockHolding alloc] init];`
3. Set Values `aStockHolding.numberOfShares = 1;` or `[aStockHolding setNumberOfShares:1]`

By synthesizing the variables, you have by default created the getter and setter methods.

---

Now, if you want to set all values in one method call..

1. Declare a method in StockHolding.h

   ```
   @interface StockHolding : NSObject

   @property (nonatomic, assign) float purchaseSharePrice;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) float currentSharePrice;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) int numberOfShares;

   - (void)setPurchaseSharePrice:(float)iPurchase andCurrentSharePrice:(float)iCurrent withTotalNumberOfShares:(int)iTotal;

   @end
   ```
2. Define method in StockHolding.m

   ```
   @implementation StockHolding ()

   @synthesize purchaseSharePrice;
   @synthesize currentSharePrice;
   @synthesize numberOfShares;

   - (void)setPurchaseSharePrice:(float)iPurchase andCurrentSharePrice:(float)iCurrent withTotalNumberOfShares:(int)iTotal {
     self.purchaseSharePrice = iPurchase;
     self.currentSharePrice = iCurrent;
     self.numberOfShares = iTotal;
   }
   @end
   ```
3. Create object in other classes as mentioned above and call

   ```
   StockHolding *aStockHolding = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
   [aStockHolding setPurchaseSharePrice:22.3 andCurrentSharePrice:12.22 withTotalNumberOfShares:120]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just concatenate multiple method calls in a single set of brackets like that. If you want to **initialise** (create a new instance of) a `StockHolding` object, you need to declare a method like this:

```
- (void)initWithPurchaseSharePrice:(float)p currentSharePrice:(float)c numberOfShares:(int)n;
```

And implement it similarly to this:

```
- (void)initWithPurchaseSharePrice:(float)p currentSharePrice:(float)c numberOfShares:(int)n {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        purchaseSharePrice = p;
        currentSharePrice = c;
        numberOfShares = n;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is called an **initialiser** method. It creates a new instance of the class and returns it.

Then, you can use it like this:

```
StockHolding *a = [[StockHolding alloc] initWithPurchaseSharePrice:2.30 currentSharePrice:4.50 numberOfShares:40];
```

Note that the actual method names, etc. can be arbitrary and don't have to correlate in any way with the names of your instance variables (unless you override getters and setters for `@property`s, but that's another story), since you still have to implement the method yourself, and you can do whatever you want in there.

---

If you have already created an instance like this:

```
StockHolding *stock = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
```

and want to set the values of the variables, you should use `@property`s instead of instance variables:

```
@interface StockHolding : NSObject

@property float purchaseSharePrice;
@property float currentSharePrice;
@property int numberOfShares;

@end
```

After that, you can set them directly like this:

```
StockHolding *stock = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
stock.purchaseSharePrice = whatever;
```

or

```
[stock setPurchaseSharePrice:2.30];
[stock setCurrentSharePrice:4.50];
```

Note that for this to work, **you do *not* have to declare or implement the setters and getters for these variables**. In other words, you can safely delete this:

```
- (void)setPurchaseSharePrice:(float)p;
- (void)setCurrentSharePrice:(float)c;
- (void)setNumberOfShares:(int)n;
```

because the compiler will add it for you automatically if you use `@property`s.

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172810/what-is-the-difference-between-ivars-and-properties-in-objective-c) and its answers for more information on the differences between instance variables and `@property`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating three different messages you can create only one message like this -

```
- (void)setPurchaseSharePrice:(float)p setCurrentSharePrice:(float)c setNumberOfShares:(int)n;
```

Then you can call it easily. The example you shown here for `NSCalendar` is the same thing a single message -

```
- (NSUInteger)ordinalityOfUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)smaller inUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)larger forDate:(NSDate *)date
```